# Merge multiple arrays with sorting order PHP

Tags: php

I have multiple arrays like.

```
$arr1 = array('11','25','363','434','333');
$arr2 = array('11','265','343','424','333');
$arr3 = array('18','235','33','4454','3354');
$arr4 = array('171','245','33','424','353');
```

How can i merge multiple arrays dynamically?

After mergeing all arrays I want this output to be sorted.

Comment: what method have you tried ?? and in what sorting order?? please provide more information

Comment: i need asc sorting order.

Answer (score 7):

It's as simple as it sounds:

```
$result = array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4);
sort($result);

var_dump($result);
```

Optionally, if you need to get rid of the duplicate values in the resulting array, use:

```
$result = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4));
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tested the code [here](https://3v4l.org/TXRcv). Hope this helps.

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('11','25','363','434','333');
$arr2 = array('11','265','343','424','333');
$arr3 = array('18','235','33','4454','3354');
$arr4 = array('171','245','33','424','353');

$merged = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3,$arr4);

sort($merged, SORT_NUMERIC);

foreach ($merged as $key => $val) {
    echo "array[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code -

```
<?php
    $arr1 = array('11', '25', '363', '434', '333');
    $arr2 = array('11', '265', '343', '424', '333');
    $arr3 = array('18', '235', '33', '4454', '3354');
    $arr4 = array('171', '245', '33', '424', '353');

    $am = array_unique(array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4));
    sort($am);

    $arrlength = count($am);

    for ($x=0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        echo $am[$x];
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```